# Hotspot not recognised as network device in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, networking, usb, arch-linux

I have a hotspot as my only method of acquiring an internet connection. My computer does not have a WiFi card. When I used Ubuntu and Manjaro, I could use the network applet to configure a broadband connection, and tethering the hotspot to my computer over USB worked pretty much out of the box. However, when I installed Arch Linux, though I could still configure the connection with `nm-connection-editor`, the hotspot would not be recognised as a valid device with which to make a connection. Tethering using my phone still works, but is very inconvenient. How do I make my computer recognise or otherwise let me use the hotspot without needing my phone?

`ifconfig -a` yields no output on the device

`lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 19d2:0166 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM
```

`dmesg`, when plugging it in

```
[62158.560510] usb 2-4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[62158.690230] usb-storage 2-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[62158.691049] scsi host7: usb-storage 2-4:1.0
[62159.695767] scsi 7:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZTE      USB SCSI CD-ROM  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[62159.696756] scsi 7:0:0:1: Direct-Access     ZTE      MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[62159.705717] sr 7:0:0:0: [sr1] scsi-1 drive
[62159.707546] sr 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[62159.713658] sd 7:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the ModemManager service, and you may have to restart your computer for changes to take effect. ModemManager will detect the hotspot and work with NetworkManager, and allow you to configure your hotspot's connection.

More info on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/USB_3G_Modem#Network_Manager